# access localhost of PC from an android phone browser vai USB not wifi?

Tags: jquery-mobile

I am developing jQuery mobile app using vs2010 in PC, I want to access localhost on my phone's browser. But I don't want to use the wifi since the connection is very slow.

Can I do it via USB?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably not.

However if you bring device in network then you can access via PC ip.